# Converting an Integral to Spherical Coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to convert the following integral to spherical coordinates

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{0}^{x^2 + y^2} y^2 dz dy dx$

My main issue is with limits of $z$.

Using limits of $x$ and $y$, I know we need to consider the upper half of the circle $x^2 + y^2 =1$

Now, $z = x^2 + y^2$ is a paraboloid opening upwards,cut off by plane $z =1$

So, by this logic the limits for $z$ should be:

$x^2 + y^2 \le z \le 1$,

I don't get how the limits of $z$ are between $ 0$ and $x^2 + y^2$,can someone please clear this confusion for me ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a $z=1$ plane. I see a $z=0$ plane.

Comment: What prevents $z$ to be limited by $0$ and $x^2+y^2$? And there is no plane $z=1$ in the problem.

Comment: it is not clear how this integral simplifies using spherical coordinates, try instead cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @Masacroso If I correctly understood the task is to convert integral rather than to evaluate it.

Comment: @User: I cannot understand the geometry of this integral, $z = x^2 + y^2$ is a paraboloid opening upwards ,if $ 0 < z < x^2 + y^2$, I can't understand how the limits of $x$ and $y$ calculated ?

Comment: Obviously $x$ and $y$ are bounded by the circle (in 3D - cylinder) $x^2+y^2=1$.

Comment: @user: Yes, you are correct about $x,y$ but I cannot see why the limits of $z$ are from $0 $ to $x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: Because they are the lower and upper limits of the rightmost integral.

Comment: @user: Ah, yes  I just looked at is problem carefully & realized that there is no such $z = 1$ plane, but still I am confused on how to convert this in spherical coordinates .

Comment: Take the equation of a surface and substitute the Cartesian coordinates with the spherical ones. Observe the axial symmetry of the problem. Cut the body by the plane going through the $z$-axis to have a clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch for solution:** as the integral is defined you have that
$$
0\leqslant z\leqslant x^2+y^2,\quad 0\leqslant y^2\leqslant 1-x^2,\quad  0\leqslant x^2\leqslant 1\tag1
$$
The spherical coordinates are given by
$$
x:=r\cos \alpha \sin \beta ,\quad y:=r \sin \alpha \sin \beta ,\quad z:=r\cos \beta \\
\text{ for }\alpha \in [0,2\pi ),\quad \beta \in [0,\pi ),\quad r\in [0,\infty )\tag2
$$
Therefore $(1)$ becomes
$$
0\leqslant r\cos \beta \leqslant r^2\sin^2 \beta ,\quad 0\leqslant r^2\sin^2 \beta \leqslant 1,\quad 0\leqslant r^2\cos^2 \alpha \sin^2 \beta \leqslant 1\tag3
$$
what simplifies to
$$
0\leqslant r\cos \beta \leqslant r^2\sin ^2\beta \leqslant 1\tag4
$$
What remains is to find the range of valid values for $r, \alpha $ and $\beta $ from $(4)$ and it defining bounds (stated on $(2)$), and rewrite the integral accordingly.

Comment: But we are integrating over upper half of circle , $0 < y <\sqrt{1-x^2}$, so $\alpha$ should be $0$ to $\pi$, is this incorrect ?

Comment: It seems like that @sat091...

Comment: @sat091 yes, you are right... the original condition $0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$ gives $\sin\alpha \ge 0$ so $\alpha\in[0,\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

The limits of the rightmost integral are $0$ and $x^2+y^2$. Clearly $0\le x^2+y^2$ for any real $x$ and $y$. Therefore the limits are well-defined and $0\le z\le x^2+y^2$. The lateral surface of the body are the plane $y=0$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ (for $y\ge0$).